# Protractor Start Selenium server with specific Chromedriver

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

How can I start the selenium service with my current Chrome browser on my PC?

I'm updating selenium webdriver to use chromedriver version "80.0.3987.122" by using webdriver-manager command.

`\MyProject\node_modules\.bin>webdriver-manager clean`

then I update to chromedriver "80.0.3987.122" with below command.

`\MyProject\node_modules\.bin>webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 80.0.3987.122`

then output shows.

`[12:35:39] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.26.0.zip`

`[12:35:40] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_80.0.3987.122.zip`

But when I start the selenium server with command.

`\MyProject\\node_modules\.bin>webdriver-manager start`

It always uses latest chromedriver version.

`-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\MyProject\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_83.0.4103.39.exe -jar`

but version "83.0.4103.39" is not the version that I have for my current Chrome browser and that is "80.0.3987.122".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` cli has same option `--versions.chrome` as `update` cli to specify which chromedriver version to use when launching selenium server

```
\MyProject\\node_modules\.bin>webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 80.0.3987.122
```

Comment: Oh really?  thank you so much.  I will try it and get back to you.